# Redhat OS with notebook to Embedded controller RPI

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, redhat

Now I have the Redhat:Linux OS on notebook computer there are many applications inside that computer. 
Reason that I need to port Redhat:OS to RPI that computer was installed Labview application and Labview with NiDAQmx , VISA I/O.(Now it's running fine on notebook with NI6008)

The question is how can I port that linux OS to my Raspberry PI with driver of RPI?(I need to know step by step)

Comment: Please either mark as answered or update your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NI does not support running LabVIEW standard on ARM processors - see [What Linux Distributions Do National Instruments Drivers and Software Support?](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/4857A755082E9E228625778900709661).

NI does have a Real Time modules that supports ARM processors, but not the Pi - see [Targetting Raspberry PI](https://decibel.ni.com/content/thread/24941).

You can still connect a NI6008 DAQ to your Pi and access the data using a driver such as [Low Cost USB DAQ Driver for use with Raspberry Pi](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-25806), but you will have to consume the data with an application written in a language other than LabVIEW (such as Python).